# Golang mapstructure not working as expected

Tags: go

I am trying to decode a `map[string]interface{}` to a struct, but the "hours" field is not getting populated. I am using https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure for decoding. This is the struct:

```
BusinessAddRequest struct {
        Name       string `json:"name"`
        Phone      string `json:"phone"`
        Website    string `json:"website,omitempty"`
        Street     string `json:"street"`
        City       string `json:"city"`
        PostalCode string `json:"postalCode"`
        State      string `json:"state"`
        Hours []struct {
            Day                 string `json:"day"`
            OpenTimeSessionOne  string `json:"open_time_session_one,omitempty"`
            CloseTimeSessionOne string `json:"close_time_session_one,omitempty"`
            OpenTimeSessionTwo  string `json:"open_time_session_two,omitempty"`
            CloseTimeSessionTwo string `json:"close_time_session_two,omitempty"`
        } `json:"hours"`
        Cuisine []string `json:"cuisine,omitempty"`
        BusinessID int `json:"businessId,omitempty"`
        AddressID  int `json:"addressId,omitempty"`
        UserID     int `json:"userId,omitempty"`
}
```

And this is the example data:

```
{
    "name": "Agave ...",
    "phone": "(408) 000-000",
    "street": "Abcd",
    "city": "San",
    "postalCode": "90000",
    "state": "CA",
    "hours": [
      {
        "day": "monday",
        "open_time_session_one": "10:00",
        "close_time_session_one": "21:00"
      }
    ],
    "cuisine": [
      "Mexican, tacos, drinks"
    ],
    "userId": 1
}
```

All fields are getting populated except "hours".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be that you're decoding multiple times into the same `BusinessAddRequest` variable. Note this doesn't work well when you have structure elements that are slices or maps (this applies BOTH to the `mapstructure` package and to `encoding/json` as well!). Always use an empty new variable. If the repetition happens in a loop, declare the variable that you decode to in the loop body (it will be a new copy every time you run through the loop).

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"
import "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"

/* (your struct declaration not quoting it to save space) */

func main() {
    var i map[string]interface{}

    config := &mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
        TagName: "json",
    }

    plan, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("zzz")
    var data []interface{}
    /*err :=*/ json.Unmarshal(plan, &data)
    for j := 0; j < len(data); j++ {
        i = data[j].(map[string]interface{})
        var x BusinessAddRequest /* declared here, so it is clean on every loop */
        config.Result = &x
        decoder, _ := mapstructure.NewDecoder(config)
        decoder.Decode(i)
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
    }
}
```

(note I had to use a DecoderConfig with `TagName="json"` to be able to use your structure definition, which is tagged with `"json:"` and not `"mapstructure:"`).

If this doesn't help, please check your own code and try to find a minimal example similar to what I posted here that reproduces your problem and add it to the question.

Comment: Thank You much. I'm reading a JSON file and unmarshalling to the interface. I get a slice of interfaces, then I loop through the slice and convert to map[string]interface using y: = s.Index(i).Interface().(map[string]interface{}). I think I'm losing structure when I do that. Is there a better way to do it.

Comment: Not sure I understood this. What exactly are you un-marshaling to and how can it be a slice of interfaces? (the input is a JSON object, so it cannot unmarshal to a slice).

Comment: okay here is the code for reading from file `plan:=ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
 var data interface{}
 err := json.Unmarshal(plan, &data) s := reflect.ValueOf(data) for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ { y := s.Index(i).Interface().(map[string]interface{}) ...`  Above is the code I'm using to read from file and converting to map

Comment: Also, file has an array of JSON objects.

Comment: This should work, then. But... keep in mind that the decoder (that of mapstructure **as well** as that of `encoding/json`!!) will not clean up the data structure that you decode to. if you re-use the same 'BusinessAddRequest' variable to decode into, the results might not be what you expect. Also, best not to use `reflect` unless there's no other way - e.g., if you know the input data is an array, json-decode it into `[]interface{}` or (if the array elements are maps for sure), straight into `[]map[string]interface{}`. I'll update the answer to show how to avoid using the same variable twice.

Comment: Thank You. This worked :) I think Unmarshalling to an interface{} instead of []interface{} might be the problem.